# AJAX Script is not working when used in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, mobile, browser

I'm currently working on a project involving ESP32 Arduino programming for showing a webpage where users can interact with buttons for activating relays, also I implement an Slider with a short script. Is based on this project: [ESP32 Servo Motor Web Server](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-servo-motor-web-server-arduino-ide/)

Works perfectly for my purposes ... except when i try to use the web platform with no internet connection (I use the WiFi ESP32 config.) in my Android phone; I try to use the slider but it doesn't seems to be doing anything, and when i check for my Serial Monitor just looks like im not interacting with the Slider control.

Code:

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>


<p id="text_seconds">Secondss: <span id="servoPos">91</span></p>
<input type="range" min="1" max="180" class="slider" id="servoSlider" onchange="servo(this.value)" value="">
</div>
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById('servoSlider');
var servoP = document.getElementById('servoPos'); servoP.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
  slider.value = this.value;
  servoP.innerHTML = this.value;
}
  $.ajaxSetup({timeout:1000}); function servo(pos) {
  $.get('/?value=' + pos + '&'); {Connection: close};
}
</script>
```

I just tought that maybe because of the import of an external script

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

The slider just won't work, but, works perfectly when i try to use it in my laptop even with no internet connection. So, what?, Desktop browsers has extra resources that allow me for using the slider with no internet connection, or AJAX is not working ?

Comment: "with no internet connection" certainly sounds like that jQuery library wouldn't work. If you want this to run offline, include a local copy of jQuery.

Comment: I guess, but i can't explain how works with no internet connection using my laptop. Also i tried using differente web browsers, the only one that didn't work with no internet was internet explorer.

Comment: Look, your code needs jQuery, and you load jQuery off the internet. No internet, no jQuery. If it works offline, I strongly suspect it got cached; you cannot rely on the cache being there. It's a simple fix - host jQuery locally instead of via CDN if offline functionality is important to you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I am thinking is that when you visited the site on your laptop your browser cached the file so it would still function without internet. On your phone, your browser never had the chance because you have never visited with internet. So if you clear your cache on your laptop it will probably stop functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, I was working with my cache in my laptop, I required the jquery resource. Finally I implemented by my self the function that was being referencing, and now it is working smoothly.